# Why && and || cannot be used for nullable type?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AND operation cannot be applied between nullable bools.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349016/and-operation-cannot-be-applied-between-nullable-bools)

I would expect similar behavior like + or *. So if any of the operand is null, it should return null, but the compile complains if it's used in && or ||. Why?

To illustrate the point:

```
//this compiles
int? x = null;
int? y = null;
var z = x*y;

// this doesn't compile
bool? x = null;
bool? y = null;
if(x && y)
    ....
```

Comment: Can you provide some example code that fails? I'm not sure I understand what you're referring to.

Comment: "if any operand is null it should return null": The `&&` and `||` operators are of type bool and will therefore always return a boolean result. When you got nullable types simply use `myNullable.HasValue && ...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [AND operation cannot be applied between nullable bools.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349016/and-operation-cannot-be-applied-between-nullable-bools), see Eric Lippert's [excellent answer and the examples he provides](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349016/and-operation-cannot-be-applied-between-nullable-bools/4349293#4349293)

Comment: Sorry for duplication. I now understand the point why it's not supported in nature, although it may make sense in some cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it were to return `null`, then you invalidate the boolean requirement.

[`||`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx)
[`&&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx)

Basically, it would allow for a value other than `bool` (specifically, `null`) within an `if` statement which would be undefined behavior since `if` statements require `bool`ean expressions.

Interestingly, this is one of the areas where Java and C# differ. Java requires boolean values within the `if` statement as well, but they allow their version of `bool?` (`Nullable<bool>`, or just `Boolean` in Java) to be `null`. This leads to somewhat unexpected `NullPointerException`s at runtime, which C# is avoiding with this requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because && and || are short-circuiting operators. You can use & and | with bool? and I believe you get three-valued logic - null is treated as "unknown". So false & null is false, but true & null is null. This is confusing enough to keep track of, without throwing in short-circuiting too! It's possible that short-circuiting wouldn't actually be any use in the face of null values.

EDIT - On consideration, short-circuiting still makes sense for three-value logic. A logical AND with false on the left will always evaluate false, even if it has null on the right. A logical OR with true on the left will always evaluate true, even if it has null on the right. I imagine this is one of those "not worth the effort to implement" features. Sometimes you need short-circuited Boolean logic. Sometimes you need three-valued Boolean logic. But very rarely do the two overlap.

Comment: +1 Did not know ¦ and & are implemented for bool?.

Comment: The problem with short-circuiting nullable bools is what do you do if you have (null && M()) -- do you evaluate M() or not? Remember, the null might mean "there is a truth value but I don't know what it is right now". M() might have a side effect that should be evaluated **if and only if** the left hand side is true, but we don't *know* if it is true or not. The compiler isn't going to make the call for you that "I don't know" should be treated as "false" -- what if it turns out that it should have been true?

Comment: Ah, thanks. I think this is a case of differing mental models. In my head I thought of three-valued logic AND as having two inputs and one output with a nine entry truth table, and then looked at short-circuiting as the process: "evaluate input expressions from left to right until the output is unambiguous", and by this point I was just thinking of null as another value - I wasn't still treating it as a special superposition. When you consider "a && b" to be "evaluate a, if false, return false, otherwise evaluate and return b", it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Even if (x && y) was possible, result would be bool? and not bool.
If () only works with bool.

Try if (((bool)(x ?? false)) && (bool)(y ?? false)) instead.

Or better yet, following weebles' answer:

If (x & y == true).

Answer (score -3):

Nullable types are actually objects. When you apply the nullable operator '?' to a value type (such as bool), it becomes a reference to an object that holds either "null", or the value of the underlying value type.

Consider this:

```
bool? isActive;
```

This actually becomes:

```
Nullable<bool> isActive;
```

The value type actually becomes an object instance, and therefore doesn't participate in boolean expressions as regular value types do.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: Totally wrong.  `Nullable<T>` is a struct; no boxing is involved.

Comment: -1, The terms you are using are confusing. `Nullable<T>` is a structure, therefore nullable types are *value* types and hence you don't have a *reference* to a nullable type.

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes guys, but Nullable<T> does in fact box for non-null types.

Also, Nullable<T> is derived from Object.

Comment: @jscharf: deriving from Object does not mean that type to be boxed. Struct, enum, and any ValueType, in fact, inherit from Object

Comment: Well, technically no. They do after being boxed. The end result of a non-null Nullable still ends up on the heap as an Object, which is why it is not implicitly used in boolean expressions, which was my point.

Comment: @jscharf: The question has nothing to do with boxing. Of course, nullable value types [can be boxed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) if they are non-null (as the underlying non-nullable value type), but that has nothing to do with the `&&` and `||` being defined on `bool` only.