# Is there a shorthand for writing "instance && instance.boolean" without repeating "instance" twice in C#?

Tags: c#

Class *Provider* declares the boolean *isOkay*:

```
public class Provider
{
   public bool isOkay;
}
```

Class *Consumer* may use *isOkay* from a *Provider* instance:

```
public class Consumer
{
   public Provider provider; // may be null... or maybe not
   public bool IsProviderOkay()
   {
      return provider && provider.isOkay;
   }
}
```

So, is there a shorthand for writing `provider && provider.isOkay` in C# without explicitly repeating "provider"?

Something like `provider?.isOkay` would be awesome but that will raise a compile-time error because we're implicitly trying to cast a *bool?* to *bool* and, I believe (just my guess) that it is what it is because there's no way the compiler would know what to return in case *provider* is null... but I believe that's not a good enough reason. Let me explain.

Please note: the following is just an example. (I know I could use variables, methods, a different approach, ...)

Let's say I have a long logical proposition of ORs.

```
a || b || c || d || ... || z
```

Let's suppose that each of these elements (a, ..., z) are like the provider example.

```
provider && provider.isOkay
```

So, something like:

```
(water && water.hasStrongStream) || (steep && steep.isDangerous) || /*... ||*/ (mind && mind.isOverthinking);
```

What is the meaning of these elements inside the proposition?

`(water && water.hasStrongStream)` means: if you have a water module then take into consideration the stream, else ignore it.

So, I believe that `water?.hasStrongStream` looks and reads better:

- water: we're talking about a *Water* instance
- ?: if it's not null
- hasStrongStream: return its field *hasStrongStream*

What should the expression evaluates to if water is null? its default value.

This would be coherent with other language constructs such as the [Type.GetField method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getfield?view=net-7.0): if no field is found, the default value (null) is returned.

So, that's why I believe a shorthand like that is more compact and easier to read.

Comment: `provider?.isOkay == true` or `provider?.isOkay ?? true` either way you need to tell the compiler if `default(bool?)` should be `true` or `false`.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. It is ***illegal*** to write `provider && provider.isOkay`.

Comment: provider <-- why this can compare to bool ?

Comment: Are you requesting a C# feature? Because that's not the right place for it.

Comment: @Enigmativity, it's legal if `static bool operator true(ClassName value)` is defined

Comment: @JL0PD - You'd have to agree that that's an edge case that would be unexpected and would, possibly, lead to writing some hard to maintain code.

Answer (score 3):

*BTW. `provider && provider.isOkay;` doesn't even compile in C#; what works is: `provider != null && provider.isOkay`*

---

When it comes to your helper method you can shorten it to:

```
public bool IsProviderOk() => provider?.isOkay == true;
or 
public bool IsProviderOk() => provider != null && provider.isOkay;
```

For a series of checks I think `x?.IsOkay == true` works well:

```
if(p1?.IsOkay == true 
|| p2?.IsOkay == true 
|| p3?.IsOkay == true)
{
   Console.WriteLine("At least one provider is okay");
}
```

You may also want to have a look at [AND operation cannot be applied between nullable bools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349016/and-operation-cannot-be-applied-between-nullable-bools)

---

If you want to play code golf, which I don't recommend, you could also use `|` & `&` operators:

```
Provider? p1 = new Provider { IsOkay = true};
Provider? p2 = new Provider { IsOkay = false};
Provider? p3 = null;

if((p1?.IsOkay | p2?.IsOkay | p3?.IsOkay) == true)
    Console.WriteLine("At least one provider is okay");
else
    Console.WriteLine("All providers are not okay");

if((p1?.IsOkay & p2?.IsOkay & p3?.IsOkay) == true)
    Console.WriteLine("All providers are okay");
else 
    Console.WriteLine("At least one provider is not okay");
```

This will print:

```
At least one provider is okay
At least one provider is not okay
```

Answer (score 2):

That would be the coalesce operator `??`.

```cs
public class Consumer 
{
    public Provider? provider; // If this might be null, declare it as such.

    public bool IsProviderOkay() 
    {
        return provider?.isOkay ?? false;
    }
}
```

The same also works in combination with other statements:

```cs
public class Consumer 
{
    public Provider? provider;
    public Provider? provider2;

    public bool IsProviderOkay() 
    {
        return (provider?.isOkay ?? false) && (provider2?.isOkay ?? false);
    }
}
```